# gtk-recordmydesktop Set FPS Higher than 50?

Tags: video, recordmydesktop, capture, video-recording

So I recently found this program in the Ubuntu Software Store called Record My Desktop, aka gtk-recordmydesktop. I tried out the software, and it's amazing. With the configuration I used, I was able to get amazing quality, and it didn't use much of my processing power. This is great since my system specs are crap, and I primarily want to use it for recording video games.

However, in the graphical interface (I'm not sure if there's a terminal interface), I can't set the capture FPS to anything above 50. I want to be able to capture at 60. I don't want to have to take the time to find another one just like it because I can't record at 60.

I'm not sure if there even IS a recording software in existence that can capture at such a high quality for as little performance hit other than Nvidia Shadowplay or AMD Relive, which my crappy GPU isn't compatible with. Any help?

Comment: You could always edit source, although I'm not sure how that would effect performance going above 50 FPS.  I don't use it, because it has myriad conversion problems with the default output format from ogv if you upload to youtube.  I use ffmpeg with no gui to record at exactly the settings either youtube or vimeo want, so there is no re-encoding.  It would be nice if there were a switch for ffmpeg to say "initially record as raw frames, then re-encode to my specified format later when I hit Ctl+C".  That is the sole advantage of GtkRecord.

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that it is easy enough to modify the Python *installed* source to gain 60 fps for your generated files. I have successfully tested the following technique under both Trusty Tahr and Xenial Xerus:

Modify the installed Python source with the following 2 commands performed *one after the other*:

```
sudo sed -i_bak 's#lower=1, upper=50,#lower=1, upper=60,#' \
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/recordMyDesktop/rmdPrefsWidget.py

sudo sed -i_bak 's#lower=1, upper=50,#lower=1, upper=60,#' \
/usr/share/pyshared/recordMyDesktop/rmdPrefsWidget.py
```

If you wish to revert these changes simply run the following 2 commands performed *one after the other*:

```
sudo mv -v /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/recordMyDesktop/rmdPrefsWidget.py_bak \
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/recordMyDesktop/rmdPrefsWidget.py

sudo mv -v /usr/share/pyshared/recordMyDesktop/rmdPrefsWidget.py_bak \
/usr/share/pyshared/recordMyDesktop/rmdPrefsWidget.py
```

**Screenshot:**

And below is a screenshot showing the successful changes on my own system:

[image]